# Kotlin Invoke getter of KMutableProperty

Tags: kotlin

I have a KmutableProperty1Impl for a field of an object.
I would like to be able to invoke the getter for this object.
I can do property.call to access it via reflection, but I would like to do it via the public getter for that field. Can I do this?

Comment: Just use `property.get()`?

Comment: Or `property.getter` for acquiring a getter itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
YourClass::class.memberProperties.find { it.name == "PropertyName" }!!.getter.call(rect)   // explicitly

YourClass::class.memberProperties.find { it.name == "PropertyName" }!!.call(rect)   // will also call the getter
```